# bash shell script variable assignment

Tags: linux, shell

I am trying to assign an array length to a variable.

```
servers=(apple orange)
len = ${#servers[@]}
```

it says len command not found.
why?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't have spaces between your variable name and the assignment operator `=`. If you do it will treat the variable name as a command.

Try:

```
len=${#servers[@]}
```